# Binding to DevExpress GridControl TotalSummary

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a basic newbie binding question, which isn't necessarily directly related to the control used. Anyway, here's the thing: I have a DXGrid with a TotalSummary defined, which counts the rows of the grid.

```
<dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
    <dxg:GridSummaryItem x:Name="grdCompleteCount" FieldName="ar_id" SummaryType="Count"/>
</dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
```

Now I'd like to display the count not at the bottom of the grid as it is done automatically, but would like to bind it to another element, say, a textblock. Something like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="statusBarGridCount" 
           Text="{Binding ElementName=grdCompleteCount, Path=Value}"
           TextAlignment="Right" 
           Width="190" />
```

But this approach doesn't work as I'm not sure how to get to the value I'm looking for. What's wrong with the binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it already, don't worry... :) Works that way:

```
<StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="1" Margin="1">
    <TextBlock x:Name="statusBarGridCount"
            Text="{Binding ElementName=grdList, Path=VisibleRowCount}"
            TextAlignment="Right"
                />
 </StatusBarItem>
```